# .htaccess not functioning as expected

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

This seems super simple..  But I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I am designing a page: `index.html`.  I would like to redirect ALL traffic to `index.html`.  The caveat is, that I have two images on this page.  `image1.jpg` and `image2.jpg` ... That will end up being a redirect that will never complete.  So I have come up with the following:

```
# Turn On ReWrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

# Exclude image1.jpg and image2.jpg from redirecting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(image1|image2)\.jpg

# Redirect to index.html
RewriteRule . index.html [NC,L]
```

It works .. IE if I go to:

`http://mysite.com/nothing`

It works flawelessly.  What I can't figure out, is if I go **in** one directory, the images won't show .. IE

`http://mysite.com/direcotry/file.whatever`

How do I get the images to show when URL is in "nth" number of directories??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very common problem people face when they start using so-called pretty URLs.

**Solution**: Solution is to use **absolute URLs** for including your image, css and js files.  Make sure URLs in `src` attribute always start with either a forward slash (`/`) or with `http://`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have an installation of `mod_rewrite` handy to run a test, but this might be what you want.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([^/]+/)*(image1|image2)\.jpg`